# An $E$ field with no $B$ field in a region?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

Assume there exists a time-varying current source ${\bf J}({\bf r},t)$ in otherwise vacuum and a region $R$ that does not intersect the region of support for ${\bf J}({\bf r},t)$ (That is ${\bf J}({\bf r},t)=0$ in $R$). For the quasistatic case can there be a non-zero electric field in $R$ if the magnetic field is zero in $R$?

Comment: How do you get a zero magnetic field if $\bf J$ is nonzero? Is there another magnetic source somewhere? Or are we restricting the discussion to arrangements of $\bf J$ that produce zero magnetic field in the region $R$?

Comment: Yes. Restricting to $\bf J$ such that the magnetic field is zero in $R$ as stated.

Comment: You're okay with $R$ having 0 volume? For example, if $R$ is a plane.

Comment: No. $R$ should be a volume. Sorry should have stated that.

Answer (score 1):

So [we know](http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester2/d14_ampere_cylinder.html) that when we have a current flowing uniformly in a cylindrical shell, there is no magnetic field in the interior of the shell.

Suppose that on one half of the shell the current was provided by negative charge flowing from left to right, and on the other half of the shell, the current was provided by positive charge flowing from right to left. Now you still have a uniform current on the shell, so no magnetic field in the interior of the shell. But you have negative charge on one side and positive charge on the other, so there will be an electric field pointing from one half of the shell to the other.

Arranging a real physical scenario where you could have positive currents exactly matching negative currents on such a shell with no fixed charge present to balance the current-carrying charges is left as an exercise for the reader.

**Edit**

In comments you added,

> what if the charge density is zero in the region that supports **J**(r,t)?

I'm not sure I can give you a complete answer, but Maxwell's equations only offer two sources for electric fields: non-zero charge density or changing magnetic fields.

Your universe has no regions with non-zero net charge density, so this source doesn't exist here.

In the usual case where we consider sinusoidally changing magnetic fields, they will produce sinusoidally changing electric fields, which will produce further magnetic fields. So wherever there are electric fields there will also be magnetic fields.

Possibly there's some scenario where the magnetic field is monotonically and uniformly increasing in some region ($\frac{d{\bf B}}{dt}={\rm constant}$). Then it could produce a constant electric field outside the region of the magnetic field.

Again, constructing a real physical scenario where magnetic field increases with constant rate indefinitely is left as an exercise. (As well as finding a geometry that produces electric field in a region with zero magnetic field)

Comment: Sorry to make this a moving target question but what if the charge density is zero in the region that supports ${\bf J}({\bf r},t)$?

Comment: Thanks, The Photon. I am trying to make intuitive sense out of a result that I obtained which seemed a bit odd at first. When I make sense of it I will post it here and clear this up. Thanks again.